# Is the nextInt method of the Scanner class an accessor or a mutator in Java?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner, accessor, mutators

My textbook defined a mutator method as a method that modifies the object on which it operates.

And, it defines an accessor method as a a method that queries the object for some information without changing it.

Am I correct in saying nextInt is an accessor method?

My reasoning is that nextInt does not modify the object on which it operates. If I have created a Scanner object called in, when I write "int a = in.nextInt();" it does not modify the actual Scanner object. Instead, it is used as a kind of getter method to assign a value to a.

Comment: You are correct, it returns the token scanned as an int, see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, from the javadoc:

> public int nextInt(int radix)
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.**
>
> ...

This tells that the state of the scanner is altered after calling the method. So this makes `nextInt` a mutator.

Therefore, `nextInt` is both a mutator and an accesor.

Answer (score -2):

You are partially correct @Nishant. The nextInt() method in the Scanner class does return the next value that is to be given as input from the keyboard. But we always use 'mutator' only for getters in java that returns the specified property of an object. So we cannot name nextInt() as a mutator. To answer your question, nextInt() is neither an accessor nor a mutator. Hope I was clear.